# Apache Camel JUnit to test messages sent to redirected route

Tags: apache-camel, junit5

I am trying to test route `app.cash.source-endpoint-quartz` from my junit which internally redirect the flow to another route `app.accrual.source-endpoint-direct`.

In my case the scenario is like `app.cash.source-endpoint-quartz` sends few messages to MQ, after that the processing continues and based on certain condition it will redirect to route `app.accrual.source-endpoint-direct` and which eventually sends few more messages to same MQ.

How do I test this?

**Cash Route**

```
from("{{app.cash.source-endpoint-quartz}}")
            .routeId("cash-route")
            .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, logger,"***** CASH ROUTE STARTED *****")
            .doTry()
                ...
                ....
                .to("direct:cashTransactionRoute")                                                                                              //Sub Route
                .process(c -> {
                    TransactionMaster transactionMaster = (TransactionMaster) c.getIn().getHeader(Constants.HEADER_TRANSACTION_MASTER_CASH);
                    transactionMasterService.updateMsgStatus(transactionMaster, Status.SUCCESS);
                })
                .bean(transactionManager, "markSuccess")
            ...
            ...
```

**Cash Sub Route**

```
from("direct:cashTransactionRoute")
        .routeId("cash-transaction-route")
            ...
            .split(simple("${body}"))
            .parallelProcessing()
                ...
            .end()// End of split() and parallelProcessing()
        .end()
        .process(e -> {
            ...
        })
        .choice()
            .when(simple("${body.size} != 0"))
                .process(e -> {
                    e.getIn().getBody();
                })
                .to("{{app.accrual.source-endpoint-direct}}")                                                                   //Redirect to accrual route
            .end()  //End of choice
        .end();
```

**Accrual Route**

```
from("{{app.accrual.source-endpoint-direct}}")                                                                                  //Accrual Route
        .routeId("accrual-route")
        .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, logger,"***** ACCRUAL ROUTE STARTED *****")
        ...
        ...
```

**application-test.yaml**

```
app:
    cash:
      source-endpoint-quartz: direct-vm:cash
      txn-type: CASH
    accrual:
      source-endpoint-direct: direct-vm:accrual
      source-endpoint-quartz-1: direct-vm:accrual-quartz-1
      source-endpoint-quartz-2: direct-vm:accrual-quartz-2
```

Below is my JUnit which I tried but getting error.

```
@RunWith(CamelSpringBootRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, properties = {"camel.springboot.java-routes-include-pattern=**/Cash*, **/Accrual*"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class, SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = {"test"})
public class CashRouteTest {


    @EndpointInject(value = "{{app.cash.source-endpoint-quartz}}")
    private ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;

    @EndpointInject(value = "{{app.accrual.source-endpoint-direct}}")
    private ProducerTemplate producerTemplateAccrual;

    @EndpointInject(value = "{{app.mqservice}}")
    private MockEndpoint mock;

    @Test
    public void cashRouteTest_PaymentWithAccrual() throws Exception {

        Mockito.when(...).thenReturn(.....);
        Mockito.when(...).thenReturn(.....);
        ...

        producerTemplateAccrual.start();
        producerTemplate.start();
        producerTemplate.sendBody(null);
        //producerTemplateAccrual.sendBody(null);

        mock.expectedMessageCount(4);
        mock.expectedBodiesReceived();

        Assert.assertEquals(4, mock.getExchanges().size());
        String xml = String.valueOf(mock.getExchanges().get(0).getIn().getBody());
        MessageEnvelope messageEnvelope = (MessageEnvelope) XmlUtil.toObject(xml);
        String actualPayload = XmlUtil.toXml(messageEnvelope.getPayload());
        String expectedPayload = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>....";
        Collection<TransactionMaster> txnMasters = (Collection<TransactionMaster>) txnMasterRepo.findAll();
        Collection<Transaction> txns = (Collection<Transaction>) txnRepo.findAll();
        logger.info("actualPayload : {} ", actualPayload);
        Assert.assertEquals(expectedPayload, actualPayload);
        Assert.assertEquals(2, txnMasters.size());
        Assert.assertEquals(4, txns.size());
        Assert.assertEquals(Status.SUCCESS, Status.forValue(txnMasters.iterator().next().getRefStatusId()));
        Assert.assertEquals(Status.SUCCESS, Status.forValue(txns.iterator().next().getRefStatusId()));
        mock.assertIsSatisfied(5000);
    }
}
```

When I run this JUnit I get below error.

```
2019-07-25 10:36:47,179 [main] INFO  o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext - Route: cash-route started and consuming from: direct-vm://cash
2019-07-25 10:36:47,179 [main] INFO  o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext - Route: cash-enrich-route started and consuming from: direct://cashEnrichRoute
2019-07-25 10:36:47,179 [main] INFO  o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext - Route: cash-transaction-route started and consuming from: direct://cashTransactionRoute
2019-07-25 10:36:47,179 [main] INFO  o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext - Total 3 routes, of which 3 are started


Message History
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RouteId              ProcessorId          Processor                                                                        Elapsed (ms)
[cash-route        ] [cash-route        ] [direct-vm://cash                                                              ] [     32018]
[cash-route        ] [log1              ] [log                                                                           ] [         9]
[cash-route        ] [doTry1            ] [doTry                                                                         ] [         0]
[cash-route        ] [bean1             ] [bean[com.app.service.DbTransactionManager]                         ] [       500]
[cash-route        ] [bean2             ] [bean[com.app.service.CashTransactionSearch]                        ] [        15]
[cash-route        ] [choice1           ] [when[simple{Simple: ${body.size} == 0}]choice[]                               ] [       204]
[cash-route        ] [process1          ] [Processor@0x20bc4c09                                                          ] [        15]
[cash-route        ] [process2          ] [Processor@0x1ca6323c                                                          ] [        16]
[cash-route        ] [to1               ] [direct:cashEnrichRoute                                                        ] [       130]
[cash-enrich-route ] [split1            ] [split[Simple: ${body}]                                                        ] [       130]
[cash-route        ] [process3          ] [Processor@0x5aac9d67                                                          ] [       235]
[cash-route        ] [process4          ] [Processor@0x753cc26d                                                          ] [        75]
[cash-route        ] [to2               ] [direct:cashTransactionRoute                                                   ] [         0]
[cash-transaction-r] [split2            ] [split[Simple: ${body}]                                                        ] [       385]
[cash-transaction-r] [process16         ] [Processor@0x20b3bbe7                                                          ] [         0]
[cash-transaction-r] [choice3           ] [when[simple{Simple: ${body.size} != 0}]choice[]                               ] [         0]
[cash-transaction-r] [process17         ] [Processor@0x5190ae57                                                          ] [         0]
[cash-transaction-r] [to5               ] [{{app.accrual.source-endpoint-direct}}                            ] [         0]

Stacktrace
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
org.apache.camel.component.directvm.DirectVmConsumerNotAvailableException: No consumers available on endpoint: direct-vm://accrual. Exchange[ID-SPLS1800411-10N-1564022207351-0-3]
```

I see that when it loads the context it does not start the accrual route. Even though I have specified `producerTemplateAccrual.start();` in my junit.

```
2019-07-25 10:36:47,179 [main] INFO  o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext - Route: cash-route started and consuming from: direct-vm://cash
2019-07-25 10:36:47,179 [main] INFO  o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext - Route: cash-enrich-route started and consuming from: direct://cashEnrichRoute
2019-07-25 10:36:47,179 [main] INFO  o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext - Route: cash-transaction-route started and consuming from: direct://cashTransactionRoute
2019-07-25 10:36:47,179 [main] INFO  o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext - Total 3 routes, of which 3 are started
```

Comment: Junit5 is not supported in Apache Camel yet. Alex is working on this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-13342

Comment: ProducerTemplate and route are not the same. The template is for sending message, and the route is for routing message. Make sure the route which you see is not started is part of your testing, eg its discovered by spring/camel or you need to add it manually etc. Its harder to tell as you havent shown so much code for that part etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, properties = {"camel.springboot.java-routes-include-pattern=**/Cash*, **/Accrual*"})
```

Cash*, **

Because of the space after , the AccrualRoute was getting ignored.

After removing the space both the routes are getting loaded.